# Usage of msiexec.exe in a yaml script

Tags: powershell, validation, yaml, gitlab-ci, windows-installer

I have currently a yml script in my gitlab project that runs on a powershell environment in a Windows 7 Enterprise in order to automate some actions as part of my CI process.

I added a line that hangs the process, it never finishes... I suspect the command for some reason is not 100% powershell friendly:

```
- 'msiexec.exe /i "$vars["setup"]" /qn /L*V "F:\Logs\install.log"'
- 'msiexec.exe /x "$vars["setup"]" /qn /L*V "F:\Logs\install.log"'
```

So I decided to change it for a new command with the counterpart that has many ' and ", so the yml validator does not accept it:

```
- '(Start-Process -FilePath msiexec.exe -ArgumentList "/i $vars['setup'] /qn /L*V 'F:\Logs\install.log'" -Wait -PassThru).ExitCode'
- '(Start-Process -FilePath msiexec.exe -ArgumentList "/x $vars['setup'] /qn /L*V 'F:\Logs\install.log'" -Wait -PassThru).ExitCode'
```

My question is, what would be the best way to install and uninstall an application in this context? (first or second option (or even a new one))

And what should I correct to run it?

Many thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Here the complete *.gitlab-ci.yml*:

```
installAndUninstallNewestSetup:
  stage: installAndUninstallNewestSetup
script:
  - '$vars=@{}'
  - '$vars["base"]="\\setupfolder\Debug"'
  - '$vars["setuppath"] = gci $vars["base"] -Directory | sort CreationTime -desc | select -f 1'
  - '$vars["setuppath"] = $vars["base"]+"\"+$vars["setuppath"].Name'
  - '$vars["setupname"] = gci $vars["setuppath"] | Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq ".msi" } | sort CreationTime -desc | select -f 1'
  - '$vars["setup"] = $vars["setuppath"]+"\"+$vars["setupname"].Name'
  - 'echo $vars["setup"]'
  - '(Start-Process -FilePath msiexec.exe -ArgumentList "/i **$vars["setup"]** /qn /L*V F:\Logs\install.log" -Wait -PassThru).ExitCode'
  - '(Start-Process -FilePath msiexec.exe -ArgumentList "/x **$vars["setup"]** /qn /L*V F:\Logs\install.log" -Wait -PassThru).ExitCode'
tags:
  - SuperDupperApp
when: manual
```

Answer (score 2):

No idea *how* that script gets run as PowerShell has its own script file format and it's not YAML. However, there are a few issues I can spot:

```
msiexec.exe /i "$vars["setup"]" /qn /L*V "F:\Logs\install.log"
```

This would expand to

```
msiexec.exe /i "System.Collections.Hashtable[" "setup]" /qn /L*V "F:\Logs\install.log"
```

I guess you can spot where things to wrong. Your second approach won't work for very much the same reason, of course. General rules for native command argument handling in PowerShell:

1. Don't try to be clever
2. Use `--%` to keep things simple if you don't need expansion

In your case I guess the following should suffice:

```
msiexec.exe /i $vars["setup"] /qn /L*V F:\Logs\install.log
```

Keep in mind that the argument list is still parsed and evaluated by PowerShell, so once you start with quotes, PowerShell will apply the usual rules for strings, which you don't want here. This is in contrast to text-based shells like `cmd`, which simply do text expansion and then try to execute whatever results from that.

When debugging such things it's always helpful to have a native command that can just print out its arguments, e.g. something like the following:

```
class EchoArgs {
  static void Main(string[] args) {
    System.Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++) {
      System.Console.WriteLine("[{0}]: <{1}>", i, args[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joey, I simplified the way I call msiexe.exe avoiding extra "" so I used a normal var and also I removed the quotes for the log. (I have partially followed your advice: 'Don't try to be clever' ;) ) BUT I would still do not know why gitlab-runner does not like some powershell statements that hang it forever... (like in my first example)

Comment: I have no way of debugging, nor a way of knowing. Something obviously goes wrong and I can see why the native command doesn't get passed what you want it to get passed, but apart from that I'm not sure why it would cause the script to hang.